# What's the best server / network architecture for powerful web development?

Tags: linux, lamp, rackspace-cloud

What I have:

- Cloud Hosting + CDN

What I want:

1. Multiple development servers, ideally assigned to a sub-domain (e.g dev.domain.com) - Some of these will be used for in-house work, other for clients
2. I want to push changes from these dev servers (through subversion) to independent staging servers, and finally, to production server
3. I want to have multiple servers for databases, client-side content
4. I want to use a LAMP stack (with Zend Framework)

I will eventually upgrade to RedHat for the Linux distribution, but I want to know the best way to 1) map everything out 2) what distribution would be good for now (I'm thinking centOS)

Answer (score 0):

That's old-school. Take a look at [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). Build on homogeneous distributed computing.